# How to attach classes from another module into jar?

Tags: java, maven

I've got multi module Maven project, let's name it `module1` and `module2`, then when I'm building jar with sources of `module2` (using `maven-jar-plugin`) I want to attach some classes from `module1`.

I want to mention, that `module1` is building before `module2`.

I tried to use `<include>` tag with path for `module1/target` directory but without success.

What's correct way to achieve this?

Comment: Add it as a dependency

Comment: Ok, but let's say I don't want to add it as another *.jar dependency, but include it with this jar. Is it possible?

Comment: Don't go outside the module.  Use module1 as a dependency.

Comment: What do you mean by "include it with this jar"?

Comment: I mean, when I've building *.jar with sources (*.class files) from module2, I want to attach inside it, few *.class files from module1

Comment: `.class` are not sources. The sources are `.java`. It's unclear what you're asking here. What exactly are you doing when you're "building with sources"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the pom.xml in  module2, include the module1 as dependancy

${project.version} will return the value of the version of parent project

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.abc</groupId>
        <artifactId>abc-module2</artifactId>
        <version>${project.version}</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding the module as a dependency will work